# App/Controller not found in REST API Project

Tags: php, psr-4

This is pure php project

Here is my composer.json code , when i debug "CatalogController.php" file , it gives me following error . Please help me to resolve this incident

https://prnt.sc/26jxg3y

Folder Structure

https://prnt.sc/26jxgyt

CatalogController.php - https://prnt.sc/26jxjw9

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Exception;

use App\Controller;
use App\CatalogModel;
use App\JwtMiddleware;
use App\RequestMiddleware;
class CatalogController extends Controller {
......
}
```

composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "klein/klein": "^2.1",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\": "App/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "App/Controller",
      "App/Middleware",
      "App/Model"
    ]
  }
}
```

[+Updated]

Thanks my team. I resolved 90% . But i got this error.
https://prnt.sc/26jzpxp

Please help me to resolve this incident.

Comment: Have you dumped your auto loader recently?

Comment: Yes sir. i did it . but same results in there

Comment: @ChrisHaas Here is my controller class - https://prnt.sc/26jxjw9

Comment: Although probably not related to your problem, the classmap portion of a composer file is for non-PSR code (I think). It might be worth it to trash your vendor folder, and rerun composer install along with the dump. If that fails, you might have to crack open vendor/composer/* files to see if your code is listed.

Comment: Oh wait. Your controllers are in a Control folder, so they should be in the `App\Controller` namespace

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas , It has been resolved now  . i have one question . I m not familiar with code debug option. when i debug "CatalogController.php" using phpstorm  it gives me following error - https://prnt.sc/26jxg3y, when i run " php -S 127.0.0.1:8000" my code will run without having any errors. i m really confused .here are the screenshots- https://prnt.sc/26jxv7o, https://prnt.sc/26jxv4w,https://prnt.sc/26jxux0

Comment: You might have to make PhpStorm aware of your composer file, although I don’t remember the specific settings. You might be able to just quit and relaunch, and one of the info popups might ask to synchronize settings with composer.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks. i m not familiar with PHP REST API , if i create REST API using php, do i need to run server.using php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 command ? currently i m trying to run it using WAMP server . but its not success

Comment: `"App\"` isn't a valid json string. Use `"App\\"` instead which has two backslashes instead of one.

Comment: @AmrithSudarshan, can we clean your question up somehow, it along with your comments, are jumping all over the place. I’m not sure what the best way is, either. We generally want a question to be focused on a single problem, which I’d take to be your titular one. Maybe you should post new question about running this and your klein/klein namespace issues. Also, screenshots are really hard to troubleshoot. Please post the text of your errors, along with the relevant lines that they reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. invalid namespace `App` or directory structure, read PSR-4 manualto understand how it use
2. redundant import `use App\*;` in `CatalogController.php` - this classes in `App` namespace too
3. invalid JSON `"App\"`
4. redundant `classmap` section in `composer.json` - read Composer manual to understand how it use

Comment: Thanks @WinterSilence , I added your recommendations . now 90% resolved. but i got new vendor related error . could you please check that ? https://prnt.sc/26jzpxp , https://prnt.sc/26jzq2t

Comment: @Amrith Sudarshan you require composer autoloader?

Comment: yes sir - https://prnt.sc/26jzswb , here is my folder structure -https://prnt.sc/26jztd5 , Here is the autoloader class map  -https://prnt.sc/26jzv67 , https://prnt.sc/26jzvm1

Comment: visually all fine, check vendor directory - klein package installed?

Comment: yes, i double checked @WinterSilence

Comment: remove "classmap" from `composer.json` and move up `routes/`. run `composer update` + `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: When i run my REST API via on "php -S 127.0.0.1:8080" then it works without having any issue. when i debug this code, then i got this error. its really strange. i m using WAMP server

Comment: maybe opchache, maybe something other... my magic ball don't work today..